# APIs for a Instagram feed viewer

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I wish to implement an Instagram feed reader for my website. A reader that will show my Instagram feed in a unique interactive manner without asking the user to login to Instagram. Is there a way for me to do this reliably using Instagram APIs or their new Instagram Business APIs?

Current options and their caveats:

**1. The Instagram v1 API found here (https://www.instagram.com/developer/)**
requires user to authenticate. There is no way for an application to use `grant_type=client_credentials` to acquire a token and make API calls.

The tokens generated don't seem to expire but a note says they may expire any time, making a solution that uses a manually generated token unreliable.
https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

**2. Instagram Business accounts API found here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/)**
requires an Instagram business account, and at the same time the queries to media endpoint seem to require User Access Token, which again requires a user to login for generation/renewal of token. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/)

I'm aware of endpoints like `https://www.instagram.com/{username}/media/`, but this is undocumented and can disappear any moment.

I will highly appreciate any help, or recommendation to implement such a feed that does not require a user to generate authentication tokens.

Answer (score 0):

as it is said in Instagram API doc:

> In your application, you should have each user go through an authentication and authorization flow in order to receive a valid access_token.

so I can see just too ways:

1. use '/media' end-point until it is blocked (i believe it is relatively reliable, because anything can disappear one day, not just undocumented things)
2. authenticate yourself on instagram, and use your own access_token for API requests, as it is done in several popular tools for getting instagram recent posts